# Google Drive SDK does not list app files if app is disconnected/reconnected from drive

Tags: google-drive-api

I have an application that lists the files it has created in google drive. It's scopes therefore include:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file
```

What I find is that if a user uses google drive's "manage apps" to disconnect and then reconnect the app, the api will no longer return any of the files that were created before it was disconnected.

The only way for these files to become visible is to open the file directly from google drive. If you do that then even if the app does not edit the file, the file will now be returned by the listing API.

This looks like a fault in the API to me and not intentional. Are there any workarounds aside from requesting the excessive permission of full access to the drive so that the application can discover its files that Google won't give it?